# AngularJs,Using fadeIn & fadeOut when scope data added or removed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I have a todo list,with the js:

```
function todoCtrl($scope) {

     $scope.todos = S('todos', []);

     $scope.addTodo = function() {

        $scope.todos.unshift({

            text: $scope.todoText,

            done: false

        });

        $scope.todoText = '';

      }

      $scope.remove = function($index) {

        $scope.todos.splice($index, 1);

       }
}
```

and the html is:

```
<div id="scope" ng-controller="todoCtrl">
    <div id="todoAdd">
    <h3>Todo List</h3>
    <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
        <input class="input" ng-model="todoText"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:120px;" id="todolist">
    <div style="width:320px;margin-left:42px;margin-top:40px;" ng-repeat="todo in todos track by $index">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" ng-change="todochange(todo)">
        <p class="todoP todo{{todo.done}}" ng-click="remove($index)">{{todo.text}}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I add ng-animate css:

```
.ng-enter 
{
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    opacity:0;
}
.ng-enter-active 
{
    opacity:1;
}


.ng-leave 
{
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
}
.ng-leave-active 
{
    opacity:0;
}
```

**The problem is when I add or remove an item,always the last item fadeIn or fadeOut,not the element that I add or clicked.Why?Please tell me.**

Comment: making working sample on plnkr or fiddle could really help you to get answer.

Comment: but i think it is because you doing splice, so after your action, the last element (by  index) will disapper.

`a=[1,2,3,4,5];a.splice(1,1);console.log(a[1],a.length)`

use delete - it not rebuilds indexes

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of this issue is that the ngRepeat DOM is associated with $index by using "track by" expression. By using "track by" in ng-repeat directive, Angular will $destroy/re-create DOM only if the association between object and DOM which defined in "track by expression" does not exist.

Let's discover how "track by $index" work and figure out why does the last item always fadeIn/fadeOut when user add/remove todo item.

## Case: Add todo item

We assume that the todo data is empty and the repeated DOM is:

```
<div>{{todo.text}}</div>
```

### Step 1: User added a todo item with text "0"

**DATA:**

```
todos = [{text:"0",done:false}];
```

**Association between $index and DOM:**

```
$index0 <=====> <div>0</div>  //new association
```

Because this association does not exist, DOM "0" will fadeIn.

### Step 2: User added a todo item with text "1"

**DATA:**

```
todos = [{text:"1",done:false},{text:"0",done:false}];
```

**Association between $index and DOM:**

```
$index0 <====> <div>1</div>
$index1 <====> <div>0</div>  //new association
```

Again, new association: $index1 <====>  0 does not exist, create a new DOM and fadeIn. You can find that the fadeIn DOM will always be the last item of the ngRepeat list.

## Case: remove todo item

Assume that the todo data is

```
[{text:"3",done:false},{text:"2",done:false},{text:"1",done:false},{text:"0",done:false}]
```

### Step 1: User remove {text:"2",done:false} object

**DATA:**

```
todos = [{text:"3",done:false},{text:"1",done:false},{text:"0",done:false}];
```

**Association between $index and DOM:**

```
$index0 <=====> <div>3</div>
$index1 <=====> <div>1</div>
$index2 <=====> <div>0</div>
$index3 // removed association
```

The association between $index3 and DOM does not exist, so remove the DOM and todo item fadeOut.

Because $index is the identifier of DOM, the last item of ng-repeat list will always be the created/destroyed DOM. If you want to benefit from "track by" expression, try to use:

```
ng-repeat="todo in todos track by $id(todo)"
```

Here is a [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/47z8e/2/)